# Setting up a Perforce (P4) server on Assembla

Tags: version-control, perforce

I'm trying to follow a tutorial at https://helpdesk.assembla.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1690364-use-perforce-with-assembla , but as a first time user, the instructions are not intuitive to me.

I've ran into the following troubles:

1. "Run 'p4 info'" 
   When I use the windows Run and search for "p4 info", it says "Windows cannot find p4 info". How do I exactly Run it?
2. How do I open the command line interface for P4?

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the installer for Perforce did not add the p4 executable to your PATH environment variable, you will have to do so manually. Then you can type p4 'command' to run p4 commands. Either that or cd to the directory where the p4.exe is and then you may run the p4 commands.

If you do not know how to add an executable to the PATH environment variable; [here is the msdn tutorial.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537574(v=office.14).aspx)

If you do not know where the p4 installer placed the p4 executable, simple navigate to the drive you chose it to install on (most likely C:) and open the Program Files and/or Program Files (x86) (depending on install) directories. In the search box in windows explorer, type p4.exe. Then copy the full path to the executable.